# Crea una aplicación que consista en hacer una petición Ajax

Tags: javascript, html

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Random User API</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label for="num-users">Número de usuarios:</label>
            <input type="number" id="num-users" name="num-users">
            <label for="country">País:</label>
            <input type="text" id="country" name="country">
            <button type="button" id="btn-search">Buscar</button>
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("btn-search").addEventListener("click", function() {
                var numUsers = document.getElementById("num-users").value;
                // var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
                var url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=" + numUsers;
                // if (country) {
                //  url += "&nat=" + country;
                // }
                fetch(url)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        var users = data.results;
                        var html = "<ul>";
                        users.forEach(user => {
                            html += "<li>";
                            html += "<img src='" + user.picture.large + "' alt='" + user.name.first + "'>";
                            html += "<p>Nombre: " + user.name.first + "</p>";
                            html += "<p>País: " + user.location.country + "</p>";
                            html += "<p>Email: " + user.email + "</p>";
                            html += "</li>";
                        });
                        html += "</ul>";
                        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html;
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.error(error));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Crea una aplicación que consista en hacer una petición Ajax (Utilizando el método que consideres oportuno) a la API REST https://randomuser.me/
Se mostrarán 2 cajas de texto, una para pedir el número de usuarios a mostrar y otra para filtrar los usuarios por el país que introduzca el usuario.

Si pedimos 10 usuarios y el país es Spain, mostrará de esos 10 solo los que sean de Spain.

Para cada usuario mostrar:

*Nombre (first), país (country), correo electrónico (email) y foto (large).*

Conseguí que imprimiese según el numero de el label pero no según el país, y cuando no haya nadie de ese pías no imprima nada

Comment: https://randomuser.me/documentation#nationalities

Comment: lo que pasa es que necesito que cuando en el label ponga por ejemplo que queremos que me muestre 20 ususarios de esos 20 usuarios filtre los que sea de el pais que elegi en el otro label

Comment: Pero si filtras despúes de la consulta ya no tendrías 20....estas seguro?

Comment: si, de esos 20 que pido solo quiero los que son de el pais que seleccione

Comment: Favor coloca el intento que hiciste de filtrado

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es condicionar con **IF country** para que te muestre los **usuarios** que en su defecto pertenezcan al país indicado de esta manera.

```js
document.getElementById("btn-search").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var numUsers = document.getElementById("num-users").value;
  //OBTENEMOS EL VALOR INGRESADO DEL INPUT PAIS
  var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
  var url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=" + numUsers;

  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      var users = data.results;
      var html = "<ul>";

      users.forEach((user) => {
        //AQUI ES DONDE CONDICIONAMOS QUE OBTENGA LOS USUARIOS DONDE LA PROPIEDAD COINCIDA EN COUNTRY
        if (user.location.country == country) {
          html += "<li>";
          html +=
            "<img src='" +
            user.picture.large +
            "' alt='" +
            user.name.first +
            "'>";
          html += "<p>Nombre: " + user.name.first + "</p>";
          html += "<p>País: " + user.location.country + "</p>";
          html += "<p>Email: " + user.email + "</p>";
          html += "</li><br>";
        }
      });
      html += "</ul>";
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Random User API</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <label for="num-users">Número de usuarios:</label>
    <input type="number" id="num-users" name="num-users" required>
    <label for="country">País:</label>
    <input type="text" id="country" name="country" required>
    <button type="button" id="btn-search">Buscar</button>
  </form>
  <div id="results"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Observaba que querías hacerlo desde la petición en la URL, pero esta es una forma sencilla, dime si funciono.